# Find a text range in column and write search result to other column in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have got a table like as this:

[image]

If the keyword which in column b, is in the sentences in column a, I want the result to be printed in column c. Like as:

[image]

Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `C2`, formula copied down :

```
=IFERROR(LOOKUP(1,-SEARCH(B$2:B$8,A2),B$2:B$8),"")
```

[image]

Comment: Can you share this excel for me? It doesn't work on my computer :/

Comment: Now its ok :) I change `,` to `;` and formula language to Turkish. And now its working. Thank you so much.